# How to Consuming RestFull Web Service in Xamarin using HttpClient Post Method.?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am Creating simple Application Using Xamarin Cross-plateform. in first page i am enter the number and click button.when user click button than i want to send this number from Xamarin to web service and if number match than get response in json.

This is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ScorpionTracker.Models
{
    public class DocketInfoModel
    {
        public string DocketNo { get; set; }
        public string PODScanFlag { get; set; }
        public string DocketDate { get; set; }
        public string FromToLoc { get; set; }
        public string ConsignorName { get; set; }
        public string ConsigneeName { get; set; }
        public string NoOfPackages { get; set; }
        public string ChargeWeight { get; set; }
        public string EDD_Date { get; set; }
        public string Delivered { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
        public string Latitude { get; set; }
        public string Longitude { get; set; }
        public string PODDocumentName { get; set; }
        public Boolean IsSuccess { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ScorpionLogin.xaml.cs

```
using ScorpionTracker.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using ScorpionTracker.ViewModels;
using ScorpionTracker.Util;

namespace ScorpionTracker.Views
{
    public partial class ScorpionLogin : ContentPage
    {
        DocketInfoModel docketInfoModel = new DocketInfoModel();
        public ScorpionLogin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        async void onClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            docketInfoModel.DocketNo = DocketNo.Text;
            ScorpionTrackerViewModel getDocketDetail = new ScorpionTrackerViewModel(docketInfoModel);
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ScorpionDocketDetails(docketInfoModel));
        }
    }
}
```

ScorpionTrackerViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;
using ScorpionTracker.Models;
using ScorpionTracker.Util;

namespace ScorpionTracker.ViewModels
{
    public class ScorpionTrackerViewModel
    {
        public DocketInfoModel _docketInfoModel;
        public string GET_DOCKET_DATA;

        public ScorpionTrackerViewModel(DocketInfoModel docketInfoModel)
        {
            this._docketInfoModel = docketInfoModel;
            getDocketDetails();
        }
        private async Task<DocketInfoModel> getDocketDetails()
        {
            // string strpost = "";
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConstantData.BaseUrl);
            string docketno = _docketInfoModel.DocketNo;// this number i am sending from web service side.
            StringContent str = new StringContent(docketno, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            //var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("DocketNo", docketno) });
            var response = await client.PostAsync(ConstantData.GET_DOCKET_DATA, str);
            var docketDataJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            DocketInfoModel docketinfomodel = new DocketInfoModel();
            if (docketDataJson != "")
            {
                docketinfomodel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DocketInfoModel>(docketDataJson);
            }
            return docketinfomodel;
        }
    }
}
```

End Of Complilation i get Exception NameResoluationException. i don't no how to solve this i search in google but did't get any solution.please if any one know comments.
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: NameResolutionException sounds like the DNS lookup for your server is failing

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/6783/system-net-webexception-name-resolution-error-when-calling-calling-wcf-services-in-mono-android-appl

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few things. You may have left them out by mistake, but if not, then your problem might be one of them.

- Are you setting `GET_DOCKET_DATA` anywhere? If not, then you are not passing (from what I assume is) the full URI for your service call.
- Does your service call work from the browser (or another application that can make POST like Fiddler)? Need to make sure your endpoint works.
- Instead of `PostAsync` maybe try [`SendAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138136(v=vs.118).aspx) instead. That's the one that I use for both POST and GET.
- You are calling your asynchronous method `getDocketDetails` synchronously in the constructor. Don't do that. Constructors are for memory allocation and especially not for asynchronous calls. Remove it from the constructor and change your method to something like this:

```
async void onClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    docketInfoModel.DocketNo = DocketNo.Text;
    ScorpionTrackerViewModel viewmodel = new ScorpionTrackerViewModel(docketInfoModel);
    var docketDetail = await viewmodel.getDocketDetail()
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new ScorpionDocketDetails(docketDetail));
}
```

As a side note, if you set up `ScorpionTrackerViewModel` as the BindingContext for ScorpionLogin.xaml.cs then you don't have manually new it up and you can have the Command for the button wired directly to the method `getDocketDetails' assuming you convert it to a public command. But this is just a suggestion to clean up the pattern.

Comment: "GET_DOCKET_DATA" just add by mistak. i have already added ConstatData.GET_DOCKET_DATA were i added WebService url.

Comment: I have also checked url in browser and it's work fine. i use SendAsync Instead of PostAsync but the same error arise.